# PBS jobs queue then immediately exit sometimes

Tags: hpc, pbs, torque

I've been using a PBS managed computing cluster for a few years now at my school. A few months ago I ran into this problem and they were never able to figure it out. When I submit jobs, they queue and then some run immediately. I believe that the jobs that should stay queued because of lack of resources die pretty much immediately. This happens intermittently depending on how many nodes I can use at one time. Sometimes I submit say 10 jobs, the first two will run, the next three will fail, then the next five will run.

I do not get either stdout or stderr files created for these failed jobs. The ones that do run do create these files. I get an email when these jobs die which I've attached here with some identifying information removed. Exit status -9 means "Could not create/open stdout stderr files" but I don't know how to fix that problem since it's so intermittent.

```
PBS Job Id: 11335.pearl.hpcc.XXX.edu
Job Name:   mc1055
Exec host:  m09/5
Aborted by PBS Server
Job cannot be executed
See Administrator for help
Exit_status=-9
resources_used.cput=00:00:00
resources_used.vmem=0kb
resources_used.walltime=00:00:02
resources_used.mem=0kb
resources_used.energy_used=0
req_information.task_count.0=1
req_information.lprocs.0=1
req_information.thread_usage_policy.0=allowthreads
req_information.hostlist.0=m09:ppn=1
req_information.task_usage.0.task.0={"task":{"cpu_list":"9","mem_list":"0","cores":0,"threads":1,"host":"m09"}}
Error_Path: CLUSTERNAME.hpcc.XXX.edu:/PATH/TOSCRIPT/run/mc1055.e11335
Output_Path: CLUSTERNAME.hpcc.XXX.edu:/PATH/TOSCRIPT/run/mc1055.o11335
```

I also looked at qstat -f right when a job failed and it's below. If I don't catch it right away it disappears from qstat.

```
Job Id: 11339.pearl.hpcc.XXX.edu
    Job_Name = mc1059
    Job_Owner = USERNAME@CLUSTERNAME.hpcc.XXX.edu
    resources_used.cput = 00:00:00
    resources_used.vmem = 0kb
    resources_used.walltime = 00:00:00
    resources_used.mem = 0kb
    resources_used.energy_used = 0
    job_state = C
    queue = default
    server = CLUSTERNAME.hpcc.XXX.edu
    Account_Name = ADVISOR
    Checkpoint = u
    ctime = Mon Jan  4 20:02:25 2021
    Error_Path = CLUSTERNAME.hpcc.XXX.edu/PATH/TOSCRIPT/mc1059.e11339
    exec_host = m09/9
    Hold_Types = n
    Join_Path = n
    Keep_Files = n
    Mail_Points = a
    mtime = Mon Jan  4 20:03:14 2021
    Output_Path = CLUSTERNAME.hpcc.XXX.edu/PATH/TOSCRIPT/mc1059.o11339
    Priority = 0
    qtime = Mon Jan  4 20:02:25 2021
    Rerunable = True
    Resource_List.nodes = 1:ppn=1
    Resource_List.walltime = 50:00:00
    Resource_List.var = mkuuid:1e94a3e50dd44803bab2d3a7c2286ee2
    Resource_List.nodect = 1
    session_id = 0
    Variable_List = PBS_O_QUEUE=largeq,
    PBS_O_HOME=/PATH,PBS_O_LOGNAME=USERNAME,
    PBS_O_PATH=lots of things
    PBS_O_MAIL=/var/spool/mail/USERNAME,PBS_O_SHELL=/bin/bash,
    PBS_O_LANG=en_US,KRB5CCNAME=FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_404112_hd4Yty,
    PBS_O_WORKDIR=/PATH/TOSCRIPT/run,
    PBS_O_HOST=CLUSTERNAME.hpcc.XXX.edu,
    PBS_O_SERVER=CLUSTERNAME.hpcc.XXX.edu
    euser = USERNAME
    egroup = physics
    queue_type = E
    etime = Mon Jan  4 20:02:25 2021
    exit_status = -9
    submit_args = -l var=mkuuid:1e94a3e50dd44803bab2d3a7c2286ee2 -v KRB5CCNAME
     /PATH/TOSCRIPT/run/tmp/montec_1059
    start_time = Mon Jan  4 20:03:14 2021
    start_count = 1
    fault_tolerant = False
    comp_time = Mon Jan  4 20:03:14 2021
    job_radix = 0
    total_runtime = 7.218811
    submit_host = CLUSTERNAME.hpcc.XXX.edu
    init_work_dir = /PATH/TOSCRIPT/run
    request_version = 1
    req_information.task_count.0 = 1
    req_information.lprocs.0 = 1
    req_information.thread_usage_policy.0 = allowthreads
    req_information.hostlist.0 = m09:ppn=1
    req_information.task_usage.0.task.0.cpu_list = 5
    req_information.task_usage.0.task.0.mem_list = 1
    req_information.task_usage.0.task.0.cores = 0
    req_information.task_usage.0.task.0.threads = 1
    req_information.task_usage.0.task.0.host = m09
```

Comment: Finally got the answer from the super computer cluster people. It's an authentication issue on their end that has no plans to be resolved since they're switching away from the current scheduler. Wish I had a better outcome but it is what it is.